# swift: defer non-optional object initialization

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, optional-parameters

When dialing with CocoaTouch, it often happens that UIView(Controller) subclass properties can't be initialized in `init` method (ex. we need view already loaded), but logically they are non-optional and even non-var. In such cases the property must be optional to compile without errors, what looks pretty ugly - the code is fulfilled with `!`.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I would imagine some deferred initialization. Perfectly if such property can compile without initial value and crash at runtime if it's accessed prior to be initialized.

Some code sample to describe the issue:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!
    let viewBasedParam: CustomClass // how to keep it non-optional if it can be initialized after view has been loaded?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewBasedParam = CustomClass(self.someLabel.text)
    }
}
```

P.S. `CustomClass` can't have default initializer, because it requires data from view.

Comment: You could try making it `lazy`.

Comment: You could also use the builder pattern

Comment: @ILikeTau, yeah, possible, but this approach is very limited - I must write dedicated initialization code for the property (ex. `lazy var viewBasedParam = self.specialMethodToInitThisParam()`). I'm looking for general solution to be able to assign initial value from any place, even by external code.

Comment: You should use implicitly unwrapped optionals, just like you are for `UILabel!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've discovered the workaround solution may be following:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var someLabel: UILabel!
    private var _viewBasedParam: CustomClass? = nil
    var viewBasedParam: CustomClass {
        get { return self._viewBasedParam! } // always unwrap private optional
        set { self._viewBasedParam = newValue }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewBasedParam = CustomClass(self.someLabel.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution appears to have no advantage over just declaring `var viewBasedParam: CustomClass!`.

Comment: @rob, I couldn't declare `var viewBasedParam: CustomClass!` without initial value

Comment: @brigadir, aren't you confusing with `let viewBasedParam: CustomClass!` ? `var viewBasedParam: CustomClass!` should work, but `private(set) var viewBasedParam: CustomClass!` would be better.

Comment: @OOPer thanks for pointing to that - copy-paste mistake. Changed `let` to `var`. So now I can initialize `viewBasedParam` after `init()`, even by setting its value outside of class methods (externally). If in some case I read it while non-initialized, I get pretty clear 'unwrap' error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyVC` you can have a `convenience` `init` method where you can initialize the `let` variables. Try this and let me know if it works for you:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
let viewBasedParam: CustomClass

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
        self.viewBasedParam = CustomClass(self.someLabel.text)//else just initialize with empty string here and then assign actual value in viewDidLoad
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `self.someLabel` undefined until `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I put comment too in that line to initialize with empty string.

Comment: I'm looking how to avoid dummy initial value.